# How do I force Selenium Python to click on the correct button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium and am trying to build a scraper on this site that clicks on the "16. token URI" button, enters a number into the input field, and clicks the the Query button. But no matter how I define the element to be clicked, Selenium clicks on a different button, even thought I've copied the XPATH exactly. Obviously I can't move onto the next two steps until I solve this one. How do I force Selenium to scroll down to the 16th button and click it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://etherscan.io/address/0xd0318da435dbce0b347cc6faa330b5a9889e3585#readContract")
assert "ASMBrain" in driver.title

try:
    delay = 5
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "readcontractiframe")))
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='readHeading16']/a")
    # ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.visibility_of((element))).click()
    # driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='input_16_1']").send_keys('10')
    # driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='btn_16']").click()
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.quit()   
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Comment: What button is being clicked instead of the one you want?

Comment: Button 5, which has a different xpath.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a different xpath. Try using the href of the `a` tag.

```
time.sleep(5)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), '16. tokenURI')]")))
element.click()
```

Comment: I tried that and am still getting the same results. It clicks on button 5, not button 16.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that it's performing .click() too soon before the element is visible. Not sure how to solve that though.

Comment: @KateB This update with the `time.sleep(5)` works for me. I try to avoid using time.sleep unless nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <iframe width="100%" id="readcontractiframe" src="/readContract?m=normal&amp;a=0xd0318da435dbce0b347cc6faa330b5a9889e3585&amp;v=0xd0318da435dbce0b347cc6faa330b5a9889e3585" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="height: 1019px; padding: 0px 0.5px;" cd_frame_id_="5f818ce91d8292c77481277348168d1d"></iframe> is not clickable at point (674, 633). Other element would receive the click: <div class="alert alert-light border shadow p-3" role="alert">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
```

You had an element click interception deal with the popup first. Then proceed to click it as well.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#btnCookie"))).click()
try:
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "readcontractiframe")))
    elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(.,'tokenURI')]")))
    elem.click()
    print("Page is ready!")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```